# Обрезка ссылки до определённого '/'

Tags: python

К примеру у меня есть ссылка
`https://example.com/example.php`
А мне нужно чтобы у меня на выходе была ссылка по типу этой
`https://example.com/`
Как я могу это сделать это при помощи python?

Comment: `url[:url.rindex('/')]`

Comment: @entithat, может, оформите как ответ? а то на единственный данный ответ без слёз смотреть нельзя...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будем использовать встроенный модуль [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = [
  'https://example.com/example.php',
  'https://example.com/example.php?a=12&b=45',
  'https://example.com',
  'https://example.com/',
  'https://example.com/hello/world',
  'https://example.com/hello/world/child.php',
]

for url in urls:
    u = urlparse(url)
    print(f'{u.scheme}://{u.netloc}/') # https://example.com/
```

Либо конкретно для полных адресов:

```
url = 'https://example.com/example.php'
print(url[:url.rindex('/') + 1]) # https://example.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще вариант через регулярку. Список урлов взял у *entithat*. Спасибо.

```
import re
        
urls = [
  'https://example.com/example.php',
  'https://example.com/example.php?a=12&b=45',
  'https://example.com',
  'https://example.com/',
  'https://example.com/hello/world',
  'http://example.com/hello/world/child.php',
]
        
print([re.search('https?://[\w\-.]+/?', u).group(0) for u in urls])
    
# ['https://example.com/', 'https://example.com/', 'https://example.com', 'https://example.com/', 'https://example.com/', 'http://example.com/']
```

Answer (score -1):

возьми ссылку за переменную, и посчитай все символы, до которого нужно обрезать, к примеру:

https://example.com/ - 20 символов.

Попробуй  так:

```
a = https://example.com/
a.lower()[:20]
```

В итоге, всё что после 20-ого символа обрезается до 20-ого символа.

Если непонятно, глянь вот это:
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html

Comment: а если там не 20 символов? ну не, это капетс

Comment: тем более, что у вас `a = https://...` даже не строка...

Comment: @entithat, Я к примеру, в питоне я делал так.

Comment: @entithat, Тем более, есть функции для строк: str(), int(), float() и т.д. Также существуют методы для них, в моё ответе есть ссылка на сайт со всеми методами.

Comment: А если другой по длине корневой урл будет? Пересчитывать?

Comment: А как считать? Вручную? А зачем там lower()?

Comment: @Andy Pavlov, можно пересчитать и вручную, можно использовать обрезку путей из cmd: ../, можно использовать html ручную обрезку: ..//
В конце концов можно что нибудь наварганить на Питоне, низкоуровневое программирование и базовые знания питона это позволяют. Я просто ответил человеку, то что сам знаю. Я если и делаю проекты, то чисто для себя, и не используя сетевые модули питона, или в любом его проявлении "Сетевой код". Всё делаю локально.

Comment: @Эникейщик, хз, я по мышечной памяти написал)
Можно в принципе и без `lower()`, но там уже зависит от Фантазии человека, и от его желание. Критерий много, но ещё раз повторяюсь, ответил о чём знаю.

Comment: @entithat, Конечно всё понимаю, я в этом деле пока что ещё новичок, относительно остальных, но я базируюсь на разработке локальных проектов, которые делаю для себя. Исходя из своих принципов, обучение по питону, ограничивается гайдами на ютубе, форумами, и прочим бесплатным пока что контентом. Мой уровень в программировании на питоне, дальше функций не уходит, но в силу своего возраста(14 лет), классы для меня пока что непонятные и сложные в понимании. Так что пока что, для меня предел, - Низкоуровневое программирование на питоне. Будем честны, и не будем врать что я там какой то мега-профи).

Comment: @TerminaliusDeveloper, ну молодец, что стараетесь.